# How to return an object from the query of a table based on a object

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table a based on the object a_obj:

```
CREATE TYPE a_obj IS OBJECT (
  a1 INTEGER,
  a2 integer
);

CREATE TABLE a OF a_obj (
  CONSTRAINT a__a1__pk PRIMARY KEY (a1)
);
```

Sometime i want to select the column of a:

```
select a.* from a  -- it works
```

sometime I want to select the object a_obj.

```
 select a_obj(a.a1,a.a2) from a; --works
```

But I don't want to rewrite the name of all columns because, I can have a lot of columns to write and it's easy to forget one.

I try something like that:

```
select a_obj(a.*) from a;
```

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do that?

that doesn't work either:

```
declare 
  ret a_obj;
begin
  select a.* into ret
  from a;
end;
```

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=53d25d05cb65a164000e816751ee2844)

Comment: See 'VALUE' function and/or 'OBJECT_VALUE' (previously SYS_NC_ROWINFO$) pseudocolumn. Usage VALUE (<table_alias>) or <table_alias>.object_value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`OBJECT_VALUE` pseudo-column](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS752):

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_VALUE FROM a;
```

Or, as [@padders commented](/questions/72811660/how-to-return-an-object-from-the-query-of-a-table-based-on-a-object/72812271#comment128607845_72811660), use the [`VALUE()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjbas.htm#ADOBJ7169):

```sql
SELECT VALUE(a_alias) FROM a a_alias;
```

*Which needs to reference a table alias and not the table identifier.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a6716a3a2ebb22e8dd8a7838f36b956b)*